# VBA copying certain range of value to another new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2017/09/25/question.png

May I ask how can i let the codes automatically copy the range of data from A3 - I19 to another new workbook by clicking on the "CommandButton" .

```
Sub CommandButton()
Range("A3").Copy Range("I19")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign bellow to command button.

```
Sub CommandButton()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Dim sh As Long
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rw In Range("A3:I19").Cells
    If rw.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = rw
        Set Rng = Union(rw, Rng)
    End If

    Next

    Rng.Copy

    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

     sh = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 2

           .Activate

       .Cells(sh, "A").Select
    End with

       ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: `End With` is missing.